# How to use SecurityContext in CDI Async Events

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, cdi, jakarta-ee-security-api

We have moved some processing logic to CDI Async Observers however some of the business methods in the observers have some security checks that use `securityContext.isCallerInRole(...)` to check for specific roles.

Since the securityContext is not propagated with Async threads how can we still enforce application security within the observer? Our Custom HttpAuthenticationMechanism only works in Servlet lifecycle so its not possible to trigger authentication using this mechanism.

I cannot see any way to assign Roles/Groups in an programmatic way and the `@RunAs` annotation only seems to work for EJBs and not CDI beans

UPDATE:

Ok this actually seems to be a problem with securityContext.isCallerInRole(...) specifically as the Principal is actually set ok in the Async method but isCallerInRole is returning false.

Could be the same issue reported here: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/4734 (I am running on Wildfly 26)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't check this in any application server, but according to the CDI 2.0 spec, the container should provide the same security context to the async observer:

> **24.1.2. Observer method invocation context in Java EE**
>
> When Running in Java EE, the container must extend the rules defined
> in Observer method invocation context and must also ensure that all
> kinds of observers are called in the same client security context as
> the invocation of Event.fire() or Event.fireAsync() or
> BeanManager.fireEvent().

Comment: Thanks, I just checked again and the Principal is actually set so the identity is being propagated but isCallerInRole(..) returns false